# Fsharpc cannot generate fsi files

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to generate the fsi file for a particular fs file.

Config.fs:

```ml
namespace Web2

open FSharp.Data

module Config =

  type JsonConfig =
    JsonProvider<Sample="./config.json">

  let config =
    JsonConfig.Load("./config.json")
```

Generating the signature file:

```sh
fsharpc --sig:Config.fsi Config.fs
```

Error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

Config.fs(8,5): error FS0039: The type 'JsonProvider' is not defined.
Config.fs(8,5): error FS0039: The type 'JsonProvider' is not defined.
Config.fs(11,16): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Load' is not defined.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code in `Config.fs` depends on `JsonProvider` which comes from the `FSharp.Data.dll` library - but when you invoke the compiler, you are not specifying the dependency.

You can do that by using the `-r` command line option:

```
fsharpc -r:whatever/folder/FSharp.Data.dll --sig:Config.fsi Config.fs
```

In general, if you are compiling a project, the references are specified in the project file and so you do not need to specify them elsewhere. But when you're invoking the compiler directly, you need to do that.

Comment: Excellent Thomas, thanks! Is there any best practices to generate fsi files?